# Check whether a key exists or not in a nested JSON

Tags: java, json

I am stuck in a situation where I need to check whether a key exists in a nested JSON object. By nested JSON Object that I am having a JSON object inside the parent JSON object as the value of one of its key. So i need to check whether this key exists in entire JSON object. I am getting the below data as a `String` object. I know I can parse this `String` object to get JSON object.

```
{
"claim_loss_type_cd": "TEL",
"claim_type": "002",
"claim_reason": "001",
"policy_number": "1234kk3366ff664",
"info": {
    "ApplicationContext": {
        "country": "US"
    }
  }
}
```

I have used `containsKey()` method to check the key existence in the main JSON object and it works. But for checking any internal JSON object like "info" I need to parse that `Object` again to JSON object and then check the key again.

```
        String jsonString = "My JSON String here";
        JSONObject finalResponse = new JSONObject(jsonString);
        finalResponse.containsKey("country"); // will return false
        JSONObject intermediateResponse = (JSONObject)finalResponse.get("info");
        intermediateResponse.containsKey("country"); // will return true
```

So is there any better way, any API or method which can check inside any internal JSON object as well without the need of parsing the internal JSON object. I am using `com.ibm.json.java.JSONObject.JSONObject()` native IBM library for Websphere Application Server and No additional JSON parsers I am using.

Considering the above JSON, like "claim_type" is a key in parent JSON object but "info" in itself a JSON object.
So what i need to do is to check whether a key exists in complete JSON, either in parent or any of its child JSON object like key "country" here in example.

**EDIT:**

Thanks to @chsdk I came to a solution. But if anyone else came to any solution using some other API, please respond, because below solution is taking recursion into account & might have big Space/Time Complexity.

```
public static boolean checkKey(JSONObject object, String searchedKey) {
    boolean exists = object.containsKey(searchedKey);
    if(!exists) {      
         Set<String> keys = object.keySet();
         for(String key : keys){
             if ( object.get(key) instanceof JSONObject ) {
                    exists = checkKey((JSONObject)object.get(key), searchedKey);
            }
         }
    }
    return exists;
}
```

Comment: did you used any JSON parser like jakson etc ?

Comment: Guys, *JSON* (the word) is not code, don't format it as a code block..

Comment: @TimCastelijns somebody suggested me that JSON to mak as Code, so i accepted that suggestion for edit

Comment: If you have the JSON as a raw string, can it be checked against the regex `\"country\"\s*:` ?

Comment: @MuhammadSuleman no I am not using any additional parsers

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use **[JSONObject](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html)** to parse your json and use its ***[has(String key)](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html#has(java.lang.String))*** method to check wether a key exists in this Json or not:

```
 String str="{\"claim_loss_type_cd\": \"TEL\",\"claim_type\":\"002\",\"claim_reason\": \"001\",\"policy_number\":\"1234kk3366ff664\",\"info\": {\"ApplicationContext\":{\"country\": \"US\"}}}";
 Object obj=JSONValue.parse(str);
 JSONObject json = (JSONObject) obj;
 //Then use has method to check if this key exists or not
 System.out.println(json.has("claim_type")); //Returns true
```

**EDIT:**

Or better you can simply check if the JSON String contains this key value, for example with `indexOf()` method:

```
String str="{\"claim_loss_type_cd\": \"TEL\",\"claim_type\":\"002\",\"claim_reason\": \"001\",\"policy_number\":\"1234kk3366ff664\",\"info\": {\"ApplicationContext\":{\"country\": \"US\"}}}";
System.out.println(str.indexOf("claim_type")>-1); //Returns true
```

**EDIT 2:**

Take a look at this method, it iterates over the nested objects to check if the key exists.

```
public boolean keyExists(JSONObject  object, String searchedKey) {
    boolean exists = object.has(searchedKey);
    if(!exists) {      
        Iterator<?> keys = object.keys();
        while( keys.hasNext() ) {
            String key = (String)keys.next();
            if ( object.get(key) instanceof JSONObject ) {
                    exists = keyExists(object.get(key), searchedKey);
            }
        }
    }
    return exists;
}

Object obj=JSONValue.parse(str);
JSONObject json = (JSONObject) obj;
System.out.println(keyExists(json, "country")); //Returns true
```

Comment: I have edited my question for proper explanation. I dont want to parse the internal JSON objects. is this `has()`  method can check the whole json `String` and can check whether a key exists or not

Comment: No it doesn't check the internal JSONObjects, but you can directly check the existance of the key in your string from the beginning.

Comment: thanks but i actually want to check from any JSON method instead of manipulating with String

Comment: yes that looks promising & might solve the requirement, but what about the performance issue, calling it the method `keyExists()` recursively

Comment: There's no problem with calling it recursively, as you can see if the key exits it will not enter the loop from the beginning, and it will be called recursively only whith nested JSONObjects.

Comment: I will check & update you. I have modified the code for IBM JSONObject class.

Comment: Thanks chsdk It worked good. I changed it according to the ibm `JSONObject` class and methods

Answer (score 0):

A ready-to-go method with correct casting of types:

```
/**
 * JSONObject contains the given key. Search is also done in nested 
 * objects recursively.
 *
 * @param json JSONObject to serach in.
 * @param key Key name to search for.
 * @return Key is found.
 */
public static boolean hasKey(
  JSONObject json,
  String key) {

  boolean exists = json.has(key);
  Iterator<?> keys;
  String nextKey;

  if (!exists) {

    keys = json.keys();

    while (keys.hasNext()) {
      nextKey = (String) keys.next();

      try {
        if (json.get(nextKey) instanceof JSONObject) {
          exists =
            hasKey(
              json.getJSONObject(nextKey),
              key);
        }
      } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
  }

  return exists;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Both solutions, which suggest to iterate the JsonObject recursively, have a little bug: they don't break the iteration when they finally find the searched key. So you have to break the while-loop, otherwise the loop will continue and if there is a next key, it will check this key and so on.
The code example, which searches for the "country"-key only works, because 'country' is coincidentally the last key in its JsonObject.

Example:

```
 /* ... */
    while (keys.hasNext()) {
          nextKey = (String) keys.next();

          try {
            if (json.get(nextKey) instanceof JSONObject) {
              exists = hasKey(json.getJSONObject(nextKey), key);

              if(exists){
                  break;
              }

            }
          } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
          }
        }
    /* ... */
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue to overcome, converted JSON to Map and collecting key value pair and iterating over them to get the values which i required (its kind of calling same method again and again but feels better than recursive programming.hopefully it helps).

```
public static void jsonToMap(String t) throws JSONException {

    Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<>();
    getJsonObjectMap(t).entrySet()
        .stream()
        .filter(s->s.getKey().equals("info"))
        .forEach(u -> {
            try {
                getJsonObjectMap(u.getValue()).forEach(map::put);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
        
    map.entrySet().forEach(System.out::println);

}

private static Map<String,String> getJsonObjectMap(String t) throws JSONException {

    HashMap<String,String>  map = new HashMap<>();
    JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(t);
    Iterator<?> keys = jObject.keys();
    while( keys.hasNext() ){
        String key = (String)keys.next();
        String value = jObject.getString(key);
        map.put(key, value);
    }
    return map;
}
```